# Multicolumns to have containing box with position is fixed

Tags: css

I am using **column-width** to wrap a list horizontally.  The list is within a **fixed position** wrapper.

The wrapper has a background, but the **background is not applied to the full width of the list** when the position is fixed (or any parent's position is fixed).  The background appears fine when the position is static.

*How do I get the wrapper to contain its contents when using multicolumn layouts so that I can apply the background to the full width?*

I have an example of fixed and non-fixed positioned multicolumn layouts with backgrounds in this jsfiddle -

https://jsfiddle.net/vwLwL9cn/

```
<div class='fixedWrapper'>
    <ul>
        <li>Horse</li>
        <li>Cow</li>
        <li>Chicken</li>
        <li>Pig</li>
        <li>Duck</li>
        <li>Emu</li>
        <li>Goose</li>
        <li>Donkey</li>
        <li>Chicken</li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class='spacer'>
</div>
<div class='wrapper'>
    <ul>
        <li>Horse</li>
        <li>Cow</li>
        <li>Chicken</li>
        <li>Pig</li>
        <li>Duck</li>
        <li>Emu</li>
        <li>Goose</li>
        <li>Donkey</li>
        <li>Chicken</li>
   </ul>
</div>



.fixedWrapper {
  background: blue;
  -moz-column-width: 100px;
  -webkit-column-width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
}

.spacer {
  height: 100px;
}

.wrapper {
  background: red;
  -moz-column-width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

I suspect the reason that it doesn't work how I would like it to is because of -

https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/CR-css3-multicol-20110412/:

> Column boxes act as the containing block for their content. That is, column boxes behave like block-level, table cell, and inline-block boxes as per CSS 2.1, section 10.1, item 2 [CSS21]. However, column boxes do not establish containing blocks for elements with ‘position: fixed’ or ‘position: absolute’.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the  `position: fixed;`  in css, for a class, and if you need the background to be full 100%, then you should add  `width: 100%`  to the same class. https://jsfiddle.net/zeasts/vwLwL9cn/1/

Comment: This gives the wrapper the full width of the containing element, no matter how wide the columns of the list get.